# Combinations with mutual exclusivity

Tags: combinations

I have a set *S* of *n* elements, from which I will choose combinations of *m* elements.

Normally, this is fairly basic. However, certain elements within *S* are mutually exclusive. This can be in pairs, or larger subsets, of which only 1 can at most exist in the final combination.

Given *n* and *m*, and the sizes of all mutually exclusive subsets in *S*; how can I best determine the number of possible combinations?

If no clean way exists, what is the best way to find a decent lower- and upper bound?

Comment: General solution technique:  1) Find the number of combinations without restrictions.  2) Find the number of combinations that violate the exclusions.  3). Subtract.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am not sure I follow. 1) is an absolute lower bound and 2) an absolute upper bound, but straight subtracting the two does not seem like it could give an actual answer.

Comment: Rather, finding 2) is the actual issue at hand, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$, and you are choosing $5$ of those, but $A=\{2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$ are mutually exclusive subsets (you can only have at most $1$ from each.)

In this example it so happens to be barely possible to satisfy the requirements.  You must take exactly one of $\{2,3\}$ and one of ${4,5,6}$ and all of $C = \{1,7,8\}$ so there are $2\cdot 3 = 6$ ways.

If instead we needed to choose three items, then we have a branching tree of possibilities, depending on whether a mutually exclusive set is sampled from or not. We might take from neither $A$ nor $B$, from $A$, from $B$, or from both.  All four cases must be examined.

In the first case, there is only one choice: $\{1,7,8\}$
In the second, we choose $1$ from $A$, and two from $C$, for $6$ more ways.
In the third, we choose $1$ from $B$ and two from $C$, for $9$ ways.
In the fourth case, we choose $1$ from $A$ and one from $B$ and one from $C$, for $2\cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 18$ ways.

Altogether, that is $34$ ways.

There does not seem to be any easy formula for expressing this in general.

Comment: That's quite clear. Though the last statement is rather unfortunate. I hope you'll understand I leave this open for a bit in case someone with some arcane knowledge does have a more general approach.